# emulator is not installing app

Tags: android, emulation

i am new to android developer. i am following http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html. when i make simple hello world application first time application runs on the emulator. now i am trying to run next application.application not installed on the emulator i.e. Emulator is not showing the application name and application icon.Then i deleted both application from package explorer and restarted the laptop.then i make second application again and try to install on emulator.Emulator again not showing the application. Then i try to install hello world application on emulator this also don't work.i checked the min. sdk version and target sdk version in android manifest.xml they both are correct.Hello is the project name of second application.

console is showing

```
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Hello] ------------------------------
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Hello] Android Launch!
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Hello] adb is running normally.
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Hello] Performing com.example.hello.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Hello] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Froyo'
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Hello] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Froyo'
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Emulator] Failed to load libGL.so
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Emulator] error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Emulator] Failed to load libGL.so
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Emulator] error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Emulator] 
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Hello] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-12-28 21:23:21 - Hello] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-12-28 21:23:28 - Hello] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.hello.MainActivity activity launch'!
[2012-12-28 21:23:43 - Hello] ------------------------------
[2012-12-28 21:23:43 - Hello] Android Launch!
[2012-12-28 21:23:43 - Hello] adb is running normally.
[2012-12-28 21:23:43 - Hello] Performing com.example.hello.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-12-28 21:23:44 - Hello] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Froyo'
[2012-12-28 21:23:44 - Hello] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Froyo'
[2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Emulator] Failed to load libGL.so
[2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Emulator] error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Emulator] Failed to load libGL.so
[2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Emulator] error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Emulator] 
[2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Hello] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Hello] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-12-28 21:23:59 - Hello] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.hello.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

code of activity_mail.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    />

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

code of string.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My First App</string>
<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

after install libGL.so console donesn't shows 
         Failed to load libGL.so
         [2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Emulator] error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No                  such file or directory
         [2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Emulator] Failed to load libGL.so
         [2012-12-28 21:23:45 - Emulator] error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
but still application won,t install on emulator.

this is androidmanifest.xml file of hello application

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.second"
  android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.second.Second"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"                android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" android:showOnLockScreen="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

with regards

ajay

Comment: Can you post your home activity and was as the manifest?

Comment: not understand what u r asking?

Comment: You have the activity_mail.xml (This is the Screen Layout file) and the Strings.xml (This is just where it gets String Variables from).  But you don't have the Main Activity File (It ussually located under "src" folder). Looking at your error I believe it's called "MainActivity" And the AndroidManifest file (ussually located in the root of the project)  If you can Post those 2 files as well that may be of some help to figure out your problem.

Comment: the source code is same as given on the webpage http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html   and  i seen the android manifest.xml in that target sdk =17and min. sdk =8 both are correct.don't know what to do? should i reinstall adt plugin for eclipse by deleting eclipse and android sdk folders? for installation of eclipse and android sdk can i use their respective zip. folders.

Comment: Try setting the following in the Manifest...                android:minSdkVersion="4"  android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

Comment: i downloaded only two sdk from sdk manager they are Android 2.2 API 8 and Android 4.2 API 17.

Comment: can u provide me the link where u get this sort of information because that application install on emulator but second application doesn't installing on emulator.

Comment: emulator is now fine i used command adb kill-server and adb start-server

Answer (score 1):

It looks likes you're developing on Linux. You'll need to symlink a working libGL.so into your 32-bit lib directory. This could be as simple as "sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so".

Comment: i tried that line on terminal then i restart laptop and try to run app again but still it won't works. in console it doesn't show Failed to load libGL.so

Answer (score 0):

libGL.so belongs to the Mesa libGL runtime library. Emulator complains because it can't find 32-bit Mesa libs. Install Mesa for the i386 / i686 architecture:

Comment: i used this command sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.after using it i reinstall eclipse and i run the second app again console doesn't shows Failed to load libGL.so and emulator doesn't install application

Comment: u can follow this link also 


http://www.redips.net/android/emulator-fedora-linux/

Comment: can u provide another link or any other help appreciated?